auth cannot be resolved to a variable
<%if(auth != null){%>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="order.jsp">Orders</a>
   </li>

<%
User auth =(User) request.getSession().getAttribute("auth");
if(auth!=null){
    request.setAttribute("auth",auth);
}
    
productDao pd = new productDao(Dbcon.getConnection());
List<product> products = pd.getAllProduct(); 
    
ArrayList<cart> cart_list = (ArrayList<cart>) session.getAttribute("cart-list");
if(cart_list != null){
    request.setAttribute("cart_list", cart_list);
}
%>

Error:

auth cannot be resolved to a variable.

I don't know what to do. Help me to find the solution and I'm new here.

Well, what it says on the tin: you never declared auth to be a variable, so the compiler doesn't know what it is. Please show us a [example] if you think you did declare auth and don't understand why the compiler doesn't see it.

By the way, it looks like it should work. Try to clean and rebuild your project.

@MisuriWijewardhana just to understand, you have both those pieces of code (the one that outputs the html and the one that sets the attrbutes etc.) in that specific order? Because if that's the case you should move User auth =(User) request.getSession().getAttribute("auth"); before any use of the auth variable (so before the first piece of code).

still the same

@MisuriWijewardhana please [edit] the question and add the code you modified so we can try and fix it.

When and where is that error message appearing?

The variable auth is not defined. You should define a variable before you reference in the code as <%! some-scripting-variable %>. For details see JSP Declarations:

When the scripting language is the Java programming language, variables and methods in JSP declarations become declarations in the JSP page’s servlet class.


If you use the scripting variable in the JSP tag attribute then you should read this answer.
